# Android WebView and webrtc hello world example

Tags: android, webview, webrtc

The code I'm pasting below was built with Android Studio and tested on an Android smartphone. I'm pretty sure it was working fine as long as I manually enabled camera and microphone permissions. I also wrote a Java variant instead of Kotlin and all worked as expected.

However, I am totally unable to make this app work anymore, no matter how many times I reboot my device or make sure there are no other running apps that might use the camera or mic.

The webrtc test site mentioned in the code works fine if I load it in Chrome.

So, any ideas why my webview "test app" cannot access any media device even if I enable microphone and camera permissions in "Android OS app settings"?

And like I said, I'm pretty sure it DID work before, but something went wrong, obviously. I just want to make sure here that the code is OK.

```
package org.me.test

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val WebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        WebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        WebView.loadUrl("https://test.webrtc.org")
    }
}
```

The manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.me.test">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.test">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

</manifest>
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to use the WebChromeClient if I want webrtc to work.

Something like this seems to work for me in my MainActivity class:

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }
        });
```